# Kendo numberFormat change in culture

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, culture

I want to format numeric column value as 55,25,236.30 in grid. I created a JS function and called from column template in grid. My JS function:

```
function NumberFormater(Price) {
    kendo.culture("en-US");
    kendo.cultures.current.numberFormat.groupSize = [3,2];
    return kendo.toString(Price, "##,#.00");
}
```

but the value is showing like 5,525,236.30. According to this [link](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/definecultureinfo) the default value for `groupSize` is `[3]`. Is it not possible to set multiple values like `[3,2]` like numberformat in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the `NumberFormater` function receives a **numeric** argument. Below is a test page that works.

On a side note, I am not sure there is a need to set the `culture` and `groupSize` every time you execute the function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.default.min.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <input class="k-textbox" type="number" value="5525236.3" />
    <button id="format" class="k-button">Format numeric value</button>

    <script>

      $("#format").click(function(){
        var formattedValue = NumberFormater(parseFloat($(".k-textbox").val()));
        alert(formattedValue);
      });

      function NumberFormater(Price) {
        kendo.culture("en-US");
        kendo.cultures.current.numberFormat.groupSize = [3,2];
        return kendo.toString(Price, "##,#.00");
      }  

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks dimodi.The problem was the version,i was using kendo 2014.1.318. when i update to 2016.3.914,it is working. sabbir